# Why github says "You already have a fork of this repository"?

Tags: github

**Context**

I've had a fork, what I've deleted recently. I've checked: my repo is really deleted. I've also checked, the fork number on the original repo decreased from 3 to 2.

**Question**

Now I am trying to create a new fork from the very same repo, but github says:
"You already have a fork of this repository" 
Why github says this?. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the repo? If that's the case, check this: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

Answer (score 9):

The create fork pop-up screen can be a little confusing if you are a member of the Organisation. In this case the message "You already have a fork of this repository" is informing you that you already have a fork in your Organisation. Though you still should be able to click on your profile picture on the create fork pop-up screen. This should fork that repository into your user account.

Answer (score 0):

The situation will be less confusing, from Oct. 2018: "[**Look before you fork**](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-10-11-updated-fork-selection-modal/)":

> Keeping track of forks just got easier!
>
> When you click the “Fork” button on a repository that you’ve already forked before, **your existing forks are listed and clearly separated from other accounts that you can fork to**.