# Trying to fork any repo on GitHub throws "You've already forked..Fork again to a different account" dialog

Tags: git, github

I am simply trying to fork a repo in in GitHub and everytime I try that it throws this weird message saying "You have already forked [My project name]" and then below that it says "Fork again to a different account".

1. First of all this is a brand new project and I have at least not tries to fork it.
2. If it is already forked, where can I see the list of the projects that have already been forked from this project?

   3. What difference would it make if I fork it again as a different user as oppose to the being the same user?
   4. IF it was true that the repo has been forked before(which I think is not), I would not be able to fork it again? Why can I not have 10 forks of the same project?

Above all, How can I simply fork it without jumping so many hoops?

Comment: is this a case of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39043082/1256452 ?

Comment: Its actually different because a. I did not delete a fork b. I don't think that creating anew fork from my account should/would solve the problem. My original question is around being able to create multiple forks from the same account.

Comment: That's not what the other question is about: the key is whether you're a member of some *organization*. If the organization itself has forked the repository, and you have access to the organization, GitHub considers *you* to have forked the repository.

Comment: Have you checked if you have forked any downstream repo of the one you are trying to fork ? Apparently that can give this issue as well.

Comment: @torek, yes I am member of an org. I am not sure if org itself has already forked the repo. Is there any way on GitHub to check that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm no GitHub expert. You could ask the GitHub support folks...